# X11 KeySyms: Switch mode, KeySym groups and XK_ISO_Level3_Shift

Tags: c, x11, xlib, xorg

I'm using Xlib for a project, and I'm trying to get the KeySym relative to a pressed key.

I've got the KeyCode relative to the pressed key, keyboard modifiers and keyboard indicators. I'm referring to [this page](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/keyboard-encoding.html) to understand how to retrieve the correct key, but it must be out of date or something, because my X doesn't behave like that page says.

I've got some questions:

1. What is MODE SWITCH? How can I see what key is my MODE SWITCH and how can I set it? (via Xlib functions or via a command, it's the same).
2. That page says that the first 4 KeySyms associated to a KeyCode (found with `XGetKeyboardMapping`, or shown by `xmodmap -pk` command) are divided into two groups. MODE SWITCH switches between groups, and within a group the first or the second KeySym is chosen according to modifiers (ie, shift key) or indicators (ie, caps lock). But on my X I can see that if shift is pressed, I switch to the third KeySym, not the second one.
3. On many european layouts AltGr key is bound to KeySym `XS_ISO_Level3_Shift`, which doesn't belong to any keyboard modifier (ie, `shift`, `lock`, `control`, `mod1`, `mod2`, `mod3`, `mod4` and `mod5`). When such `XS_ISO_Level3_Shift` is pressed, the fifth KeySym associated to the KeyCode is chosen. Why? Where can I found some info about this `XS_ISO_Level3_Shift` and about other keysyms that are actually used, but not documented on Xlib manuals?

Comment: Then there is the XKeyboard extensions.  I'm far from sure that everything which is possible with them can be described in term of the more basic xlib possibilities.  Perhaps that's why you are confused if your implementation use them (`xdpyinfo | grep XKEYBOARD` to know if it is the case).  Each time I've looked at that, I started confused and then understood.  But I've never reached a state where I remembered the underlying logic of that mess.

Comment: Does your system have `xev`?  This is often a quick and simple way to resolve problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the page you're reading predates Xkb - I'd guess that content is 10-15 years old at least.

See: http://www.xfree86.org/current/XKBproto.pdf

"xmodmap -pm" will show you the modifier keys such as mode switch.

With Xkb, the behavior of basically everything is configurable, I believe. Start looking at /usr/share/X11/xkb/ for example. I don't know a lot about it but hopefully looking at Xkb instead of old docs will get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Tronche's manual is incomplete. I found more info about keyboard functions in:
1. [xlib.pdf](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xlib.pdf)
2. [xlib html manual at static.cray-cyber.org](http://static.cray-cyber.org/Documentation/NEC_SX_R10_1/G1AE02E/CONTENTS.HTML). This doc is hidden and a bit broken. Links are typed in lowercase, but the actual documents are in uppercase. After correcting the urls in browser it's readable.

PDF is complete I guess. I don't know if [2] is complete too, but for example the chapter 16.2 (sorry, I can't give a link cause my link limit is exceeded) is far longer than in Tronche's doc.

I'm a beginner in understanding xlib, that's what I managed to google out today.

Comment: breaking in with a Chapter 16.2 link: [link](http://static.cray-cyber.org/Documentation/NEC_SX_R10_1/G1AE02E/CHAP16.HTML#16.2.%20Latin-1%20Keyboard%20Event%20Functions)